# How to stop custom Timer from widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to create the widget that automatically update after every 10 sec to do this i use Timer Task. its working fine but when user remove widget i want to stop the timer to do this i put code in on Delete event in widget but its not working i mean its not stopping the timer.

Here is my Code.

```
Timer timer1;

private TimerTask updatedTimer;

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    setCategory(PreferenceData.KEY_CATEGORY, context, "");
    try {
        timer1.cancel();            
        updatedTimer.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("OnDelete",""+e.toString());
    }
}

    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {


    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

     mIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsHeadlinesActivity.class);
     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent,0);

    timer1 = new Timer();
    updatedTimer= new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updatedTimer, 1, 10000);              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can watch from the (custom?) Timer to the state of the Widget, and cancel the Timer from itself when the Widget is disable (using some Application level variable ?).